# How can I disable gzip for the specific route?

Tags: php, android, apache, laravel, .htaccess

In the Android client, we use this [downloader library](https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader). It's a great library but it needs file size before downloading the file from URL. And if you add the `gzip` downloader library it can't get the final file size(and so doesn't work).

According to some needs, we should enable `gzip` for our code (Laravel).

Now we want to disable the `gzip` for the specific route.

This is my .htaccess content :

```
SetEnv no-gzip  dont-vary
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On



    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried reporting this issue to the authors of the plugin as well? Sounds like something they should be supporting.

Comment: How are you sending your response ? can you add the action@Controller to your post ?